# Storing a complete Array in a node

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I am trying to store an array of ints in a node. I am not getting the node the way i should. Any help anyonecould give will be great.

```
  public void readIn()
  {
  int counter = 1;
     try {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("WordProblemData.txt"));
        int times = Integer.parseInt(inFile.next());
        for (int a = 1;a <= times; a++)
        {
           for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
           {
              num[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(inFile.next());
              System.out.println(num[i-1]);

           }
           data = (String)(inFile.next()); 
           System.out.println(data);



           head = new DateStampNode(data,num,head);
        }
        inFile.close();
```

Comment: What, exactly, is your problem??

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a large, preallocated array, I believe you need to allocate a new array before filling it.

You may also want to remember to increment `num`.

Comment: Thank you. The idea to allocate a new array fixed my issue.

Comment: I see. Nice to see that you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem really is (what *should* you get in your opinion?), but it might be this:

```
int[] num = new int[8]; //you should allocate a new array, otherwise you'd overwrite the values in the next iteration of the outer loop
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    num[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(inFile.next());
    System.out.println(num[i-1]);
}
data = (String)(inFile.next()); 
System.out.println(data);

//you're storing num here, so you'd need a new num array for the next iteration, see above
head = new DateStampNode(data,num,head);
```

Comment: Thank you. The idea to allocate a new array fixed my issue.